# iOS development: Testing localised views

Tags: ios, unit-testing, internationalization, swift2

According to [the official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/TestingYourInternationalApp/TestingYourInternationalApp.html), Apple recommend running the app and visually inspecting it as their preferred way of testing localised views.

I am after a way to do at least minimal levels of automated tests, analogous to Rails' `view` tests, just to check that there are no missing localisations etc. A simple sanity check.  However we've found that we can't even load `Localisable.strings` when in test mode.

How do people automatically test localised views?

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to use CocoaPods, you can install KIF, it is a wonderful library and really simple to use. You will find a lot of related subject on it.

KIF Github: https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF

Tuto for KIF: https://www.raywenderlich.com/61419/ios-ui-testing-with-kif